# Simple algebraic geometry question

Tags: algebraic-geometry, parametrization

Just started my algebraic geometry course so my understanding of ‘curves’ is shaky at best. Question reads:

> Show that there exists a cubic curve $f(x,y)$ such that every point on the parametrized curve $$x(t) = 1 + t^2,\qquad y(t) = t + t^3$$ satisfies the equation $$f(x(t),~y(t)) = 0$$ Conversely, show that for any point $(x,y)$ with $f(x,y) = 0$, with one exception, there exists a real number t with $x = x(t),~ y = y(t)$.

So I just made $$f(x,y) = tx - y = 0$$ which is trivially true (might be misusing trivially here, but whatever the equation is always 0). This seems sneaky but acceptable to me, and I feel that I made a function of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ that satisfies $f(x,y) = 0$ for all t. I answered the question without breaking any rules, or so I think. So everything seems kosher but I’m still suspicious of my answer, am wondering what another answer to the question might be, and I still fail to understand how to go about answering the second half of the question. Please help, I’m just a boy.

Sorry about the long winded and multifaceted questions, I’m a stranger to algebraic geometry that also happened to suck at most elementary algebra. Thanks.

Comment: For the first part, you should come up with an equation than doesn't involve $t$, but only $x$ and $y$ directly.

Comment: Your equation has a $t$ in it. Can you find an equation just involving $x$ and $y$?

Comment: As others pointed out, $t$ should not appear in the final answer given that it is a parameter (as opposed to a coordinate like $x$ and $y$ are). Hint: You correctly figured out that $t=y/x$. What if you plug in that value of $t$ into one of the equations?

Answer (score 0):

You have a first step, but you must completely eliminate $t$.

Multiplying the first equation by $x^2$,

$$x^3=x^2+x^2t^2$$

and using your relation,

$$x^3=x^2+y^2.$$

---

Conversely,

$$y=\pm x\sqrt{x-1}$$ or

$$\begin{cases}x=|t|,\\y=t\sqrt{|t|-1}\end{cases}$$ will work for all $t\notin(-1,1)$. Of course, the initially given parameterization works as well (without exception !).

Comment: The origin lies on $y^2=x^2(x-1)$, but is not traced by the OPs parameter $t$, when it's real. It is usually said the origin is a node of the complex curve with two complex tangents that intersect in a real point (the origin). (The tangent cone at the origin is $x^2+y^2=0=(x+iy)(x-iy)$).

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland: that's right. The first operation (multiplying by $x^2$) does introduce this extra solution. What I meant is that both parameterizations yield the same set (which excludes the origin), and the given one makes no restriction on $t$.

Comment: $t=\pm i$ gives the node, so I would not call it an extra solution in the context of algebraic curves. Also, the lines $y=tx$ are the ones to give the parameterization precisely because the origin is a node on this curve. If you (or OP) want an example where the node is visible over the reals, take $y^2=x(x-1)^2$ and $y=t(x-1)$; the lines through the node intersecting the curve one more time, just as for OP's curve.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland: I am in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Which is why I wrote “in the context of algebraic curves”.